# How would I go about adding new data to a file?

Tags: bash, grep, cut, nmap

So! I have an nmap scan that saves the output to a file, *nmapscan.txt*:

```
sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1* > nmapscan.txt
```

I also have a few other commands to clean up and save all desired output to one file, *livehosts.txt*:

```
cat ./temp/nmapscan.txt | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}' > ./temp/macaddresses.txt
```

Which saves the mac addresses. And:

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' ./temp/nmapscan.txt > ./temp/ipaddresses.txt
```

Which saves the IP addresses. And:

```
cat ./temp/nmapscan.txt | grep -o -P '(?<=for).*(?=.attlocal)' > ./temp/hostnames1.txt
```

Which saves the hostnames. And:

```
cut -d' ' -f 2 ./temp/hostnames1.txt > ./temp/hostnames2.txt
```

Which I did to clean up the hostnames (sorry, forgot to include this in original post)... And:

```
cut -d' ' -f 1 ./temp/hostnames2.txt | paste ./temp/macaddresses.txt ./temp/ipaddresses.txt - > ./temp/livehosts.txt
```

.. which is the end product that combines the desired data and displays like:

```
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx   192.168.1.1     Netgear
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx   192.168.1.111   John's Toilet Cam
```

I want to do the scan and write, again, and want the *livehosts.txt* file to be more or less, updated. Simply doing the scan and write again, as is, writes over the file. And not all devices are connected at different times.

I've tried:

```
>>
```

But that just doubles up the data already in the file.

Would doubling up the data, cutting recurring data, then writing to a new file be the best way to go about it?

How would you go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Is `nmapscan.txt` the same file as `./temp/nmapscan.txt` - or are you perhaps re-processing the same file over again?

Comment: Yeah, it's the same file. Sorry!

Comment: The easiest way is probably to double up the data, and afterwards use `sort -u`.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many manipulations that are unnecessary.

First of all, use the `-oG` option (grepable format). This will make your job easier. Source: [Nmap Reference Guide - Output](https://nmap.org/book/man-output.html). And there is no need to do file redirection (`> nmapscan.txt`) since nmap already has an `-oN` option. You can log to a file but still have output to the console.

I am not sure your target specification is even legal:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1*
```

Maybe `nmap` managed to interpret it correctly, AFAIK it's not valid syntax.

Instead, use `192.168.1.0/24` or `192.168.1.1-255` (assuming you want scan a small network with addresses 192.168.1.0 through 192.168.1.255.

See: [Nmap Reference Guide - Target Specification](https://nmap.org/book/man-target-specification.html)